# Вывод рейсов, самолетов, времени

Tags: sql

> В справочной аэропорта хранится расписание вылета самолётов на следующие сутки. Для каждого рейса указаны номер рейса, тип самолёта, пункт назначения, время вылета. Вывести все номера рейсов, типы самолётов и время вылета в заданный пункт назначения в порядке возрастания времени вылета.

Comment: Олечка,

укажите: язык, платформа, среда разработки, что сами сделали, какие трудности, что не понимаете. И еще: целиком писать программу за Вас здесь никто не будет. Только за предоплату.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать базу данных со стандартом SQL, должно подойти что-то вроде:

Список рейсов до Moscow:

```
SELECT * FROM air_shedule WHERE destination="Moscow" ORDER BY start_time ASC;
```

Все номера рейсов:

```
SELECT DISTINCT race_number FROM air_shedule WHERE 1;
```

Все типы самолетов:

```
SELECT DISTINCT plane_type FROM air_shedule WHERE 1;
```

Comment: А слова "WHERE 1" зачем нужны ?

Comment: Ну блок WHERE вроде как положен по синтаксису, не все БД принимают запросы без WHERE. А конкретно WHERE 1 это условие, которое просто всегда выполняется, т.е. выбрать все записи.

Comment: Тогда почему в первом (с ORDER BY) забыли WHERE ?

Comment: Это где перед ORDER BY стоит WHERE destination="Moscow" ?

Comment: В самом деле, слона-то я и не приметил...

---

На самом деле блок WHERE по синтаксису SQL вовсе не обязателен.

Comment: С какой-то базой, толи MSSQL, толи Oracle сталкивался с тем, что приходилось писать такой блок, с тех пор так и пошло)